# json autocomplete crashing

Tags: jquery, json, performance, autocomplete

I have 5 JSON files (3.5 MB) combined into a JavaScript array searchResult[] that have to be queried from a Search Box as follows:

var searchResult = [];

*(pardon the pseudo-code)*

```
searchResult.Push ...json file 1 
searchResult.Push ...json file 2
searchResult.Push ...json file 3
searchResult.Push ...json file 4
searchResult.Push ...json file 5

$(function () {
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete(
        {
            source: searchResult,
            minLength: 3
        });
})
```

The problem is that the autocomplete is crashing due the size of the array from the combined JSON files.

My questions is:

What would be the most efficient way to carry out such an operation without causing the autocomplete to crash.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use ajax source and filter the data server side

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I am currently doing. Below is an example of 1 of the ajax call to a json file:

 $.get("data/nav_keywords/myyJSONfile.json",
          function (data) {

              Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
                  data[k].forEach(function (i) { searchResult.push("My prefix: " + k + ', ' + i); }
                  );

              });
          }
         )

Comment: And your filtering is returning 3.5 MB???? How much data can a user absorb? Sounds like you need to rethink your filtering some more

Comment: Yes, the 3.5 MB combined files are all possible keywords that need to be searchable. I think I may need to pre-download the whole 3.5 MB onto the client first, then run the autocomplete on the downloaded content.

Comment: But why? Why can't you do the filtering at server and send a lot less?

Comment: Doing the filtering on the server will limit the keywords before the searchResult array is populated. Yes it will send a lot less but it will also not send all the keywords needed for the search.

Comment: But the autocomplete sends the keywords to server ...then you use that to filter

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the filtering on the server side and send a lot less to the client. The filtered search happens when the user fills out the autocomplete box. Can I pass what is in the autocomplete box through AJAX to bring back fewer records into my searchResult array? Is this what you mean?
a) Send filter to JSON file to return less into array
b) Query a lighter array
Please provide more details.